# Running autonomous application on screen

Tags: linux, xorg, display-server

I need to set up a linux box in a way in a way in which there is one screen that displays a web page (like an ad on a projector or something) and another screen that is a workspace for an employee with some desktop enviroment running (i.e. a monitor in an office room).

Can I run an instance of X on the ad screen that is completely independent from the workspace of the employee? I.E. The employee should not be able to interact with the ad space so the mouse and keyboard should only work on his workspace.

Is it possible (i'm quite sure it is) and if yes - how? (I didn't find sufficient documentation so far)
Thank you for any hints!

Comment: In fact, this is want you want: linuxtoys.org/multiseat/multiseat.html